# Is there an function in org-mode to refer to the "row group number"?

Tags: org-mode

I have an org table:

```
| name      | band     | group # |
|-----------+----------+---------|
| lennon    | beatles  |         |
| mccartney | beatles  |         |
| harrison  | beatles  |         |
| starr     | beatles  |         |
|-----------+----------+---------|
| page      | zeppelin |         |
| plant     | zeppelin |         |
| jones     | zeppelin |         |
| bonham    | zeppelin |         |
|-----------+----------+---------|
| mason     | floyd    |         |
| waters    | floyd    |         |
| wright    | floyd    |         |
| barrett   | floyd    |         |
| gilmour   | floyd    |         |
```

I'd like to fill the last column with the "row group number":

```
| name      | band     | group # |
|-----------+----------+---------|
| lennon    | beatles  |       1 |
| mccartney | beatles  |       1 |
| harrison  | beatles  |       1 |
| starr     | beatles  |       1 |
|-----------+----------+---------|
| page      | zeppelin |       2 |
| plant     | zeppelin |       2 |
| jones     | zeppelin |       2 |
| bonham    | zeppelin |       2 |
|-----------+----------+---------|
| mason     | floyd    |       3 |
| waters    | floyd    |       3 |
| wright    | floyd    |       3 |
| barrett   | floyd    |       3 |
| gilmour   | floyd    |       3 |
```

I'd like to do this in a way that would allow me to add more groups to the table in the future. Is this possible in org-mode?

Comment: Do you pick or assign the group a number or is the group number assigned by group order in the table? Will the beatles always be group number 1 even if it was the bottom of the table?

Comment: The beatles are group #1 because they are the first group on the list. The group number is assigned by group order in the table.

Comment: Thanks for quick response! I had a simple solution if you manually assigned number to group,`#+TBLFM: $3=@-I$3`, but it does not work if you wanted group number to be equal to group order. I'll keep looking!

Comment: @Melioratus Thanks! For now I'm inputting these by hand in a much larger org document. Hopefully I can automate this in the future!

Comment: Did my answer help? The example code will automatically assign the group number in column 3 according the order the band in column 2 of your table. If you move a band up or down in the table, the group number for that band will updated when the `#+TBLFM:` is executed again using `C-u C-c *` or `C-u C-u C-c *`. Thanks for asking your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This**

1. Add a `#+NAME:` to your org table, e.g. bands-table

   ```
   #+NAME: bands-table
   | name      | band     | group # |
   |-----------+----------+---------|
   | lennon    | beatles  |         |
   | mccartney | beatles  |         |
   | harrison  | beatles  |         |
   | starr     | beatles  |         |
   |-----------+----------+---------|
   | page      | zeppelin |         |
   | plant     | zeppelin |         |
   | jones     | zeppelin |         |
   | bonham    | zeppelin |         |
   |-----------+----------+---------|
   | mason     | floyd    |         |
   | waters    | floyd    |         |
   | wright    | floyd    |         |
   | barrett   | floyd    |         |
   | gilmour   | floyd    |         |
   ```
2. Add the code block below into your file.

   ```
     #+NAME: my/group-number 
     #+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var data=bands-table[,1,] :var band_name=""
       (setq bands (delete-dups data))
       (seq-position bands band_name)
     #+END_SRC
   ```
3. Add `#+TBLFM:` to bottom of your org table.

   ```
   #+NAME: bands-table
   | name      | band     | group # |
   |-----------+----------+---------|
   | lennon    | beatles  |         |
   | mccartney | beatles  |         |
   | harrison  | beatles  |         |
   | starr     | beatles  |         |
   |-----------+----------+---------|
   | page      | zeppelin |         |
   | plant     | zeppelin |         |
   | jones     | zeppelin |         |
   | bonham    | zeppelin |         |
   |-----------+----------+---------|
   | mason     | floyd    |         |
   | waters    | floyd    |         |
   | wright    | floyd    |         |
   | barrett   | floyd    |         |
   | gilmour   | floyd    |         |
   #+TBLFM: $3='(org-sbe my/group-number (band_name $$2))
   ```
4. Place cursor on `#+TBLFM:` and press <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-c</kbd> to populate group number column. If prompted answer yes.

   ```
   #+NAME: bands-table
   | name      | band     | group # |
   |-----------+----------+---------|
   | lennon    | beatles  |       1 |
   | mccartney | beatles  |       1 |
   | harrison  | beatles  |       1 |
   | starr     | beatles  |       1 |
   |-----------+----------+---------|
   | page      | zeppelin |       2 |
   | plant     | zeppelin |       2 |
   | jones     | zeppelin |       2 |
   | bonham    | zeppelin |       2 |
   |-----------+----------+---------|
   | mason     | floyd    |       3 |
   | waters    | floyd    |       3 |
   | wright    | floyd    |       3 |
   | barrett   | floyd    |       3 |
   | gilmour   | floyd    |       3 |
   #+TBLFM: $3='(org-sbe my/group-number (band_name $$2))
   ```

Thanks for asking a fun question!
Hope that helped!

---

> This code was tested using:
>   GNU Emacs 25.3.1
>   Org mode version 9.1.2